# many greater quantities or much greater quantities?

Tags: grammar, usage

I learned from lots of sources dealing with grammar that *many + comparative + plural verb*.
But I found recently ***much greater quantities***, and I have never come across ***many greater quantities***.

Pleas tell me why ***much greater quantities*** is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here `much` is related to `greater` and not to `quantities`. You can use `much` before the adjective or adverb in the comparative or superlative form.

You can check it [here](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/tag/much-adjective/).

Easy to understand example:

1. I have seen much bigger elephants! (They were three times bigger than these ones).
2. I have seen many bigger elephants! (They were a bit bigger, but there were a lot of elephants).

You can easily replace `many` that is related to noun with `a lot of`.

Comment: How about 'many fewer balls'?

Comment: You can replace `many` that is related to noun with `a lot of`, so your example will be `a lot of fewer balls`. @user121695